# OnMouseEnter в Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Суть такова: я создаю примитивное приложение на форме, где есть три объекта: Label1, Label2, Label3.
Хочу сделать, чтобы когда я наводил мышь на Label1 то была видна только Label2.
Когда навожу на Label2, то видна Label3, а когда на Label3, то Label1.
так вот. захожу в события объекта. выбираю OnMouseEnter прописываю ей имя. нажимаю Enter, перехожу в функцию, там пишу

```
 Label1.Visible := False;
    Label2.Visible := True;
    Lavel3.Visible := False;
```

Когда захожу в свойства объекта Label2 то там это имя функции уже прописано и когда я нажимаю Enter то перехожу в ту же самую процедуру, пытаюсь поменять ее имя, а оно меняется и в двух других объектах(а мне нужны схожие процедуры).
Что мне делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто.
Надо было присвоить имя процедуре автоматически.(вкладка "События", процедура OnMouseEnter и кнопка справа со значком "...")